# extracting specific json key/values from postgresql jsonb table

Tags: json, postgresql

I am using postgres 9.5 and i have a table like this:

```
create table t1 (
 id serial,
 fkid int not null,
 tstamp timestamp with time zone,
 data jsonb
)
```

a typical json is:

```
{
    "WifiStatistic": {
        "Interfaces": {
            "wlan0": {
                "qualityLevel": {
                    "type": "graph",
                    "unit": "string",
                    "value": "75",
                    "graphDisplayName": "Quality level"
                },
                "SNR": {
                    "type": "graph",
                    "unit": "string",
                    "value": "75",
                    "graphDisplayName": "SNR"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What 'id like as a result of a query that extract the quality level is a recordset like:

```
id | fkid | tstamp     | value | graphdisplayName
-------------------------------------------------
1  |  1   | 2017-01-22 |   75  |  "Quality Level"
```

what kind of query might i use?

Comment: `select id,fkid,tstamp,data->'WifiStatistic'->'Interfaces'->'wlan0'->'qualityLevel'->>'value','Quality Level' from t1`?..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @VaoTsun for his comment, i ended up using this:

```
select 
 tstamp, id, fkid, 
 data->'WifiStatistics'->'Interfaces'->'wlan0'->'qualityLevel'->'value' as value,
 data #>'{WifiStatistics, Interfaces, wlan0, qualityLevel}' ->'graphDisplayName' as dname
 from data;
```

i was trying to recover two values with a single json selection, that is what puzzled me.